# How to switch between two enumerations in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have 3 enumerations: type of calculation (+,-), categories for + (10 cases), categories for - (15 cases).

So how to use my enumeration so that, depending on the type of calculation, the model's instance will accept the desired listing.

```
//Example of Model
class Transaction {

    var typeOfCalculation: TypeOfCalculation 
    var category: CategoryForConsuption
}

enum TypeOfCalculation {
    case income
    case consuption
}

enum CategoryForConsuption{
    case noCategories
    case food
    case cafesAndRestaurants
    case manufacturedGoods
}

enum CategoryForIncome {
    case salary
    case debt repayment
}
```

The logic is as follows: if the calculation type is consumption, then we change to CategoryForConsuption, and if income, then we change to CategoryForIncome.

I edited model:

```
enum Accounting {
    case income(category: IncomeCategory)
    case consumption(category: ConsumptionCategory)
}

enum ConsumptionCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case noCategories = "No categories"
    case food = "Food"
    case cafesAndRestaurants = "Cafes and Restaurants"
    case manufacturedGoods = "Manufactured Goods"
    case forceMajeure = "Force Majeure"
}

enum IncomeCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case salary = "Salary"
    case deposit = "Deposit"
}
```

But now I have new problem. Because I need to use all of this for my data model (realM).
What I should to do?

Here is my old data model:

```
  @objc dynamic private var privateTypeOfCalculation: String = TypeOfCalculation.consumption.rawValue
var typeOfCalculation: TypeOfCalculation {
get { return TypeOfCalculation(rawValue: privateTypeOfCalculation)! }
set { privateTypeOfCalculation = newValue.rawValue }
}

 @objc dynamic private var privateCategoryForConsuption: String = CategoryForConsuption.noCategories.rawValue
var categoryForConsuption: CategoryForConsuption {
get { return CategoryForConsuption(rawValue: privateCategoryForConsuption)! }
 set { privateCategoryForConsuption = newValue.rawValue }
 }
```

Comment: case debt repayment - does it really compile?

Comment: no, because it is example

Comment: I'm trying to use your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `TypeOfCalculation` have [associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148):

```
enum TypeOfCalculation {
    case consuption(category: CategoryForConsuption)
    case income(category: CategoryForIncome)
}
```

And then you only need to have `typeOfCalculation` in your model:

```
class Transaction {

    var typeOfCalculation: TypeOfCalculation
}
```

I also suggest you to rename your cases and enum names:

```
enum Calculation {
    case consumption(category: ConsumptionCategory)
    case income(category: IncomeCategory)
}

class Transaction {

    var calculation: Calculation
}
```

You can then switch on `calculation` like so:

```
switch transaction {
   case consumption(let category):
       ...
   case income(let category):
       ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think that I understand what you mean. But how all of this use with realm? I want to add in my model.

Comment: @MikhailTseitlin I didn't know you were using Realm. In that case you would need to store the `type` and `category` as strings, like you have done here. You can make the `calculation` property a computed property.